# Install older versions of MySQL Workbench from source code on Arch Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench, archlinux

For a Databases class, I have to install MySQL Workbench version 6.3.10 on my Arch Linux system instead of the most recent version.  To do this, I went to the MySQL website and downloaded the source tarball for 6.3.10.  Following the instructions in INSTALL, I found all the requisite packages and installed them, so now I have to run `cmake`, and then run the makefile.  When I run `cmake`, I get an error saying mariadb is not a suitable version of MySQL (predicted given mariadb is a competitor to MySQL), but when I run make after forcing cmake through, it seems the source code itself is chalk full of errors preventing me from compiling and installing the program.  I ran `make -k` to ignore errors/warnings and the errors continued pouring in, eventually causing the whole thing to fail.  Below is a screenshot of the errors I get without running `make -k`.[image]My questions:

1) Is this a documented thing?  And is there a documented fix that I've simply missed?

2) If no to question 1, is there another way to install MySQL Workbench on Arch Linux?

...Also its worth noting that using pacman, the latest version of MySQL Workbench works perfectly fine, and has for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can find older packages at the [arch linux archive](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/) ([wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive)). From the wiki:

> The Arch Linux Archive (a.k.a ALA), formerly known as Arch Linux Rollback Machine (a.k.a ARM), stores official repositories snapshots, iso images and bootstrap tarballs across time.
>
> You can use it to
>
> - Downgrade to a previous version of one package (last version is broken, I want the previous one)
> - Restore all your packages at a precise moment (my system is broken, I want to go back 2 months ago)
> - Find a previous version of an ISO image
>
> Packages are only kept for a few years, afterwards they are moved to the Arch Linux Historical Archive on archive.org.

MySQL Workbench 6.3.10 is still available and can be found [here](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/m/mysql-workbench/). Just download the appropriate `.xz` file and install with `sudo pacman -U <file-name>`.